# Server-side processing - how to refresh the table on outside event (checkbox clicked)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

If there is a series of checkboxes defining some additional conditions on the data (like "Male", "Female") above [a server-processed DataTables table](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) and the user makes some selections -

How to tell the table to reload the new **aaData** from the server?

And is there a way to pass some parameters (like which checkboxes have been set) along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/regex.html ? Ignore regex specific code - this page shws you how to filter elements using external form.

Jovan